# R continue loop on error

Tags: r

## apparently try and trycatch do not work for this problem! Any alternative solutions?

i'm trying to make the following example code work without actually changing any code

```
result = 0
for(i in 1:10){
  result = result + i
  log("a") #I do not care about this error
  result = result + i
}
```

This should give result = 110

If i actually do it manually by copying the part inside the loop and increasing the counter it works perfectly:

```
result = 0

#iteration 1
i = 1
result = result + i
log("a")
result = result + i

#iteration 2
i = i+1
result = result + i
log("a")
result = result + i

#iteration 3
i = i+1
result = result + i
log("a")
result = result + i

#etc.
```

However my real code has about 1000 lines and needs to loop a few hundred times.

So i'd like to have some option

```
options(on.error.just.continue.the.next.line) = TRUE
```

I've read about try/tryCatch but I don't understand it correctly I think

Answer (score 11):

If you just want the code to run, you can use `try` instead:

```
result <- 0
for(i in 1:10){
  result = result + i
  try({log("a")}) #I do not care about this error
  result = result + i
}
```

> Error in log("a") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
>   Error in log("a") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
>   Error in log("a") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
>   Error in log("a") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
>   Error in log("a") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
>   Error in log("a") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
>   Error in log("a") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
>   Error in log("a") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
>   Error in log("a") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
>   Error in log("a") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

```
result
[1] 110
```

To turn off the message, use

```
try({log("a")}, silent=TRUE)
```

---

If you are worried about a larger block of code, you can wrap it in `{ }` as follows:

```
result <- 0
for(i in 1:10){
  try({                # start code block
  result = result + i
  log("a")             # I do not care about this error
  result = result + i
  }, silent=TRUE)      # end of try function
}

result
[1] 55
```

Here, the first assignment to result completes in the `for` loop. Then the error occurs which "wipes out" the execution of the rest of the code block, which is the second assignment here. However, the loop execution is allowed to continue through completion.

Comment: And what if about >100 parts of the code could possibly go wrong? I don't want to add try() around every line of code

Comment: Not a problem in some situations. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Ok, not really the solution I was looking for, I find it strange that there's no options to not wipe it out. Especially because it ignores it when I select it manually and run the block. But thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can try using a try catch block:

```
result = 0
for (i in 1:10) {
    result = result + i
    tryCatch({
        log("a") #I do not care about this error
    }, warning = function(w) {
        # comment out the next print statement for a silent warning
        print("warning")
    }, error = function(e) {
        # comment out the next print statement for a silent error
        print("error")
    }, finally = {
        # cleanup
    }
    result = result + i
}
```

Comment: And what if about >100 parts of the code could possibly go wrong? I don't want to add try() around every line of code

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using `try` in multiple places.  This is routinely done in object oriented languages like Java, C++, and C#.

Comment: i've wrapped about hundred of lines in try, but my code still doesn't work. Do I literally need to wrap every line of code in try()? This looks as extremely ugly programming to me.

Comment: You might want to post your real code.  As for your example use case, both answers given have you covered.

Comment: My code works fine outside a loop. I'm just looking for a way for it to continue within a loop as well as it does outside a loop. I don't understand why R behaves different when you add for(i in 1){  } around the code